# How can I make everything but the stop words indexed

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have read that when using dictionaries in Postgres, if a word is not recognized by any dictionary it will not be indexed. I find that troublesome. I would like everything but the stop words to be indexed.

Can I do that? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation chapter about [dictionaries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html) says:

> The general rule for configuring a list of dictionaries is to place
>   first the most narrow, most specific dictionary, then the more general
>   dictionaries, finishing with a very general dictionary, like a
>   Snowball stemmer or simple, which recognizes everything

So dumping unrecognized words does not happen because of this last dictionary of the list.

And this is how the full text parser works out of the box, so you don't have to worry about it unless you customize it.